# how to get view object in a plugin?

Tags: zend-framework, plugins

I have a controller action helper where i save a user object into the view (in an init function) like this:

```
Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->user = $user;
```

I'd like to access the object in a preDispatch method of a controller plugin so I don't have to look up the user in the database. I tried doing so like this:

```
$user = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->user;
```

But it's returning a null object. I'm hoping its because I'm doing this wrong and not because I've programmed a catch 22 inside my login logic. Is there another way to access the object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think putting the following methods into your action helper may help you here.

```php
private $user

public function init()
{
    $this->user = new user();
}

public function preDispatch()
{
    $user = $this->user;
    //Do whatever you wish with the user object.
    // although you probably don't need to do anything.
}

public function direct()
{
    Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->user = $this->user;
    //alternatively just return the user object or whatever you want to do
}
```

Then once your helper is registered you can simply do `$this->_helper->helperName()` in your controller to put the user object into the view.

Mathew WeirO'Phiney has a [good explanation of action helpers](http://devzone.zend.com/1218/action-helpers-in-zend-framework/) on devzone. Especially the purpose of the `direct()` method.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, good approach is to have a singleton class for current logged in user;  in such a case it will be accessible anywhere - plugins, views, forms.